# How to configure the Yarn cluster with spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2.7.3

I have 2 machines with 32gb ram and 8core each machine. So how can i configure the yarn with spark and which properties i have to use to tune the resources according to our dataset. I have 8gb dataset, So can anyone suggest the configuration of yarn with spark in parallel jobs running?

Here is the yarn configuration:
I'm using hadoop 2.7.3,spark 2.2.0 and ubuntu 16

```
`yarn scheduler minimum-allocation-mb--2048 
yarn scheduler maximum-allocation-mb--5120
yarn nodemanager resource.memory-mb--30720 
yarn scheduler minimum-allocation-vcores--1 
yarn scheduler maximum-allocation-vcores--6 
yarn nodemanager resource.cpu-vcores--6`
```

Here is the spark configuration:

```
spark master    master:7077 
spark yarn am memory 4g 
spark yarn am cores 4 
spark yarn am memoryOverhead    412m 
spark executor instances    3 
spark executor cores    4 
spark executor memory   4g 
spark yarn executor memoryOverhead  412m
```

but my question is with 32gb ram and 8core each machine. how many applications i can run whether this conf is correct? bcoz only two applications running parallely.

Comment: Which version of Hadoop? Which version of Spark? Linux OS Vendor and version?

Comment: Add the contents of the following files to your question (just the parameters section). yarn-site.xml, mapred-site.xml hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml, spark-defaults.conf.

Comment: I'm using hadoop 2.7.3,spark 2.2.0 and ubuntu 16 
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb--2048
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb--5120
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb--30720
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores--1
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores--6
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores--6

Comment: spark.master spark://master:7077
spark.yarn.am.memory    4g
spark.yarn.am.cores 4
spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead 412m
spark.executor.instances 3
spark.executor.cores 4
spark.executor.memory 4g
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 412m   Here is the spark conf.but my question is with 32gb ram and 8core each machine how many applications i can run whether this conf is correct? bcoz only two applications running parallely.

Comment: Edit your question and include the file contents so that everything is readable.

Comment: I have a recent blog-post on this: https://sujithjay.com/2018/07/24/Understanding-Apache-Spark-on-YARN/ .. I feel it covers a majority of your questions regarding configurations of YARN and Spark.

Comment: Hi suj1t txs for rply. Here i have doubt that, In cluster mode we will specify the spark.yarn.am.memory + spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead memory not in client mode. I have read in apache site, but In your blog spark.yarn.am.memory + spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead is written in client mode it should be in cluster mode pls verfiy whether i'm correct?

Comment: In cluster mode if we specify the 4gb ram to the yarn scheduler maximum-allocation-mb then what should be the spark Driver and Executor memory?